# NHibernate composite application - startup records for module

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate, composite

I am building a composite (Prism) WPF application. I hava managed to build some core elemets: for example module discovery from folder.
I am also using NHibernate (Fluent) to persist data. I was able to separate modules so every has it's own model and mapping, and when Prism adds module it also adds mappings to my nh configuration.

What I would like to do is to insert some startup records when a module, that has never been started, is enabled.
For example:

When I first start my app, it detects that there is no db and creates one, only with one configuration table. This table contains info about which module is enabled. Then admin can configure app through UI which modules should be enabled. Next time the app starts it detects new tabs from newly enabled modules and creates their tables using NH UpdateSchema. What I would like to do is to also insert some startup records with this table create.
I think this should be done by NH events [(NH documentation on events)](http://www.nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#events). Something like 'PostTableCreateEvent' would be nice but I can't find anything like this.

Did any of you do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Events are triggered in sessions but Schemaexport doest take sessionfactories or sessions, so you cant hook in there. For this what you want there is `<database-object><create>INSERT ...</create><drop></drop></database-object>` in xml mappings or plain sql since FNH doesnt support `<database-object>` afaik.

Option 1: add fluent and hbm.xml mappings on creation of NH-Configuration and embed Mappings with `<database-object>`

Option 2: allow Modules to take additional steps (sql) after Creation of tables ( for one of my projects i wrapped Schemaexport in my own class/Method which also creates the database itself which isnt handled by schemaexport and inserts custom data like schemaversion and configs)

Comment: Thanks Firo, I think I will go with the second option